# Shared Use Symbol

Tags: traffic, michigan

With regard to "Shared Use Symbol", the [link](https://www.wlen.com/2018/12/17/bike-lane-symbols-what-do-they-mean/) says "this symbol, also called a sharrow, is used to represent that both vehicles and bicycles are permitted to use the travel lane. The sharrow is often placed outside of parking lanes as seen in the third image. This signifies the far right lane may be used for parking as well as bicycling. If a car is parked in the shared parking lane, they are to proceed into the travel lane, if it is safe to pass the parked vehicle, and then merge back into the shared parking lane when safe to do so."

Is the link saying that the law permits parking in the shared parking lane? Personally I just think it's kind of unsafe for the bicyclists in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: Vehicle codes are far from uniform globally, or even within different states. Which jurisdiction is this about?

Comment: Oh, it's in Michigan. Thank you!